# Android close the application after share an image

Tags: android, android-intent

My application share an image but meanwhile the user is sharing the app closes in background. The log is empty, no errors, no warnings. Can you see the error?

```java
try {
    fout = new FileOutputStream(imageFile);
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, fout);
    fout.flush();
    fout.close();
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(new File(mPath));

btn1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
btn2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
watermark.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

Intent shareIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
shareIntent.setType("image/jpeg");
shareIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);

if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
    startActivity(shareIntent);
} else {
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Compartir Vía"));
}
```

Edit:

- The app never crasher, almost continue logging normally, when I open it again backs to begining.

Comment: Try using startActivityForResult

Comment: @Chris Not a criticism, just curiosity: why would `startActivityForResult()` produce a different effect?

Comment: I don't know specifically what the differences are.  However, I have found that it is different.  For example, `Activity.getCallingActivity()` does not work if you use `startActivity` instead of `startActivityForResult`.  Its a simple change that's worth a try.  Since I don't know if it'll fix your issues, I submitted it as a comment.